# What is the "FACT" word means?

Tags: c#

My professor give me this code i need to know why is the output is 720 and what is the used of FACT word in this code

```
static int Fact(int num)
{
    if (num == 1)

        return 1;

    else return num * Fact(num - 1);

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Fact(6));
} //output is 720
```

Comment: This is clearly a school question to calculate a factorial using recursion.

Comment: You should get started by reading a c# tutorial. Look here: [Methods (C# programming)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)

Comment: Aside: The missing braces on the return does not make for a friendly-to-learn example.

Comment: only if you listen to your professor in the class.

Comment: `Fact` is nothing magic or special. It is just the name your professor gave to a function. However I would recommend your professor to read _Clean Code_ from Robert C. Martin, or at least [this excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/853187). Then he should consider naming it `factorial`. That would avoid that his students need to ask such questions.

Answer (score 0):

`Fact` is short for [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial), the product of all the natural integers up to a given integer. The code snippet here implements a factorial calculation of the argument `num` in a recursive way.