# set object as 'read only' after a specified number of values given

Tags: c#, string, constants

I have an object `ex: string str` and I want to make it read-only after it changed its value twice as shown here

```cs
string str="hello world";
str="hello";
str="hi";
//good
str="sup";
//error
```

but I also want to be able to change the number of  times value can be assigned to the object
for example:

```cs
string str[limit 2]="hello world";
str="hello";
str="hi";
//good
str[limit++];
str="sup";
//good
```

is it possible?

Comment: It is not possible in C#. You could however write a class with a property that increments a counter, and throws an exception on the nth time the setter is executed.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok thank you.

Comment: It is possible in C#, but not without wrapping the object into some other type which imposes this restriction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with a string, but it's quite easy to create a class with a property that provide you such control:

```
class IrregularVariableConstThingy
{
    private int _changeCount = 0;
    private string _value;

    public IrregularVariableConstThingy(int maxChangeCount)
    {
        MaxChangeCount = maxChangeCount;
    }

    public int MaxChangeCount {get;set;}

    public string Value {
        get {
            return _value;
        }
        set {
            if(_changeCount = MaxChangeCount)
            {
                throw new Exception("Now you can't change my value!");
            }
            _changeCount++;
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this this implementation is not thread safe nor recommended, but it does demonstrate the basic concept.

Comment: Extra credit to whoever gives the link to where I stole the `Thingy` from.

Comment: Plus 1 for awesome class name: `IrregularVariableConstThingy`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind The Thingy suffix, unfortunately, is a stolen suffix... I think I'm going to start doing that at work too...

Comment: @ZoharPeled https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-declare-and-use-read-write-properties?

Comment: https://doc.artdatabankensoa.se/WebService/html/299ead04-f55d-a645-5559-afc6cd93fa25.htm i will get upvote if i get it right right?

Comment: @ZoharPeled https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355533/use-of-my-prefix-in-object-naming ?

Comment: @MustafaGursel nice try but no. I'm beginning to think it wasn't a good idea to ask this question in the comments. some mod will get angry for too much comments eventually....

Comment: @avivgood1 I'm asking specifically about the `Thingy` suffix.

Comment: Well, the `Thingy` suffix idea came from [this comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866794/naming-classes-how-to-avoid-calling-everything-a-whatevermanager#comment46818302_10422164) Totally agree with that unknown engineer.