# What names do you find yourself prepending/appending to classes regularly?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Which nouns do you find yourself putting regularly at the end of your classes?

For example, I have a habit of sticking `Info` onto classes that pass information around but don't do a great deal:

- `ImportInfo`
- `SiteInfo`

Or for Coordinating classes:

- `UserManager`
- `SecurityManager`

I end up using `Builder` quite often for string related classes, even if it barely does any building:

- `TemplateBuilder`
- `HtmlBuilder`

And of course the timeless Helper/Utility class:

- `PhraseHelper`
- `NumberUtility`
- `FileHelper`

Have you got any good, by which I mean concise and descriptive, nouns or words you regularly use to denote the class' main role?

*This question is aimed at the .NET world, but can extend to Java, C++, Python and so on.*

Comment: Related posts - [What is a better name than Manager, Processor etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5569666/465053) *,*  [Naming convention and structure for utility classes and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1271254/465053), [What's the best approach to naming classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38019/465053) , & [Naming Classes - How to avoid calling everything a “<WhatEver>Manager”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1866794/465053)

Answer (score 47):

You can take a look at [source-code-wordle.de](http://source-code-wordle.de/), I have analyzed there the most frequently used suffixes of class names of the .NET framework and some other libraries.

The top 20 are:

- attribute
- type
- helper
- collection
- converter
- handler
- info
- provider
- exception
- service
- element
- manager
- node
- option
- factory
- context
- item
- designer
- base
- editor

Comment: +1 for the link to wordle. Great way to visualize the usage of names.

Comment: Interesting to see that the framework has more types of Attributes (annotations) than Exceptions :)

Comment: adapter, controller

Answer (score 9):

I append pattern name at the end if i follow one (i.e. FooRepository).
Trying to avoid -Helper, -Manager, -Utils.

Comment: +1: those 'Helper' and 'Manager' names usually imply that you're wrapping up a procedural system and pretending it's object-oriented. There's nothing wrong with the procedural approach but if you want the benefits of object orientation then the objects should perform their own behaviour for the most part.

Comment: +1 for saying you shuold avoid Helper, Manager, etc.

Comment: What's procedural about the word Manager? Helper I can understand, and Util and Tools, but Manager seems like it lends itself to being an object.

Answer (score 7):

I use Provider and Helper a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Util

- EnumUtil
- ParseUtil
- StringUtil
- etc ...

Answer (score 4):

Base, Reader, Writer, Manager, File.. some others.

Answer (score 2):

If my class is specifically doing calculations, I will prepend Calc

Examples:

- TaxCalc
- TipCalc
- DateCalc

Answer (score 2):

`Tests` for unit test classes

Answer (score 2):

I find myself sometimes appending the name of the parent class the one I'm writing I want to inherit.  Sometimes it sounds weird especially with an Animal example (DogAnimal, FishAnimal, ...) but it makes finding subtypes easier in a list of classes.

Comment: LabradorDogCanineCarnivoreMammalVertebrateAnimalEukaryote, that sort of thing? ;-)

Comment: Although I joke, I actually don't think this is a bad idea, since in practice it's quite common to have 2-level hierarchies. WindowsThingy, LinuxThingy, MacOSThingy; LoopbackWotsit, NetworkWotsit, SerialWotsit; MysqlAdaptor, SqlserverAdaptor, SqliteAdaptor.

Comment: haha, yeah, I usually stop at two.  Most inheritance beyond that is from the API.

Comment: `IPredicate` < `PredicateBase` < `PropertyPredicateBase` < `LessThanPropertyPredicate`

Answer (score 1):

```
Factory
```

Also:

```
Provider
```

Answer (score 1):

- Factory
- Helper
- Utils
- Job
- Entity

Answer (score 1):

On occasion I use

**Target**

As in

- UploadTarget
- ProcessingTarget

I don't think I had before Silverlight / WPF but I now also use

**Converter**

As in:

- CurrentTimeDisplayConverter
- TimeDeltaConverter

Answer (score 1):

I am often using :

- Protocol (Specific protocol
  implementation)
- Manager (Class managing the process)
- Emulator (Emulate something...)

Answer (score 0):

why of course...

**Base**

works both sides.

;-)

Answer (score 0):

`Controller` and `View`.