# Original and concise class names?

Tags: oop, terminology

How can I come up with original class names that avoid generic style words such as BlahManager ?

Also how to avoid long class names ? Here's an example from Java:

`InternalFrameInternalFrameTitlePaneInternalFrameTitlePaneMaximizeButtonWindowNotFocusedState` (from com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus)

With a given a context I reckon you could shorten such names. Say have a class used in a library or sub-library such that part of the purpose of a class is implicit.

I'm not looking to start a discussion here and would like insights into the logic or reasoning used when coming up with a name.

Edit: Here's a (funny) generator link: http://projects.haykranen.nl/java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This other (closed) Stackoverflow question is so full of good insights that I can't think of anything to add, other than Sun should be looked at with "do as I say, not as I do" in mind (they generally show not even a vague desire to avoid excessive verbosity): [What's the best approach to naming classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019/whats-the-best-approach-to-naming-classes)

It includes so many good citations from great authors and programming philosophers

Comment: Nice find :) . I came accross another Q about long class names but it was too specific. Will dig into it later.